# Sincronizar hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos, archivo

Tengo un ejercicio de hilos para grabar y leer un fichero de texto en Java, pero lo que no consigo es que se sincronicen los hilos. De la forma que lo tengo los hilos interfieren el uno con el otro, y a la hora de escribir en el fichero entra a la vez el hilo para la lectura. Como podría sincronizar los hilos en el código que tengo? Gracias de antemano.

Código:

```
public class Ejercicio7 extends Thread
{       
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread hilo1 = new Ejercicio7(); hilo1.setName("hilo1");
        Thread hilo2 = new Ejercicio7(); hilo2.setName("hilo2");

        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("hilo1"))
        {
            grabarFicheroTexto();
        }
        else
        {           
            try {
                leerFicheroTexto();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}          
        }
    }

    public static void grabarFicheroTexto()
    {
        char c;
        try{
            System.out.println("Vas a escribir en un fichero de texto en Java\n");
            System.out.print("Escribe aqui: ");
            FileWriter fichero=new FileWriter("..\\Threads\\src\\ejercicio7\\Archivo.txt");
            StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
            while ((c=(char)System.in.read())!='\n')
                str.append(c);
            String cadena=new String(str);  
            fichero.write(cadena);          

            if (fichero!=null)
                fichero.close();
        }catch(IOException ex){}
        System.out.println("FICHERO ESCRITO CORRECTAMENTE");
    }
    public static void leerFicheroTexto()throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Estas leyendo un fichero de texto en Java\n");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("..\\Threads\\src\\ejercicio7\\Archivo.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;

        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(s);
        }
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza los métodos aquire and release mediante un objeto Semaphore para bloquear el hilo de lectura si se esta escribiendo y viceversa.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Ejercicio7 extends Thread

{      
    public static Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, true);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread hilo1 = new Ejercicio7(); hilo1.setName("hilo1");
        Thread hilo2 = new Ejercicio7(); hilo2.setName("hilo2");

        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {

        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("hilo1"))
        {
            grabarFicheroTexto();
        }

        else
        {           
            try {
                leerFicheroTexto();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}          
        }
    }

    public static void grabarFicheroTexto()
    {

        mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
        char c;
        String contenido = "";
        try{
            System.out.println("Vas a escribir en un fichero de texto en Java\n");
            System.out.print("Escribe aqui: ");
            FileWriter fichero=new FileWriter("Archivo.txt");
            StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
            while (true){
                c=(char)System.in.read();
                if(c == ' ')
                    contenido = "";
                if(c == '\n')
                    if(contenido.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("fin"))
                        break;
                    else contenido = "";
                contenido += c;
                str.append(c);    
            }
            String cadena=new String(str); 
            cadena = cadena.replace("fin", "");
            fichero.write(cadena);          

            if (fichero!=null)
                fichero.close();
        }catch(IOException ex){}
        System.out.println("FICHERO ESCRITO CORRECTAMENTE");

        mutex.release();
    }
    public static void leerFicheroTexto()throws IOException
    {

        mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();

        System.out.println("Estas leyendo un fichero de texto en Java\n");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Archivo.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;

        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(s);
        }
        fr.close();  

        mutex.release();

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Ejecución]

Comment: Como podría adaptar el código para que en vez de terminar de escribir en el fichero con enter ' \n ' fuera introduciendo la palabra "fin"??

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para que si pulsas enter y la ultima palabra introducida es 'fin' el programa se detenga y guarde en el fichero el texto escrito hasta ese momento, en caso de que pulses enter y la ultima palabra escrita no sea fin, el programa te deja seguir escribiendo. No sé si es eso a lo que te refieres.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) para sincronizar los accesos al metodo.

Esto lo que hace es que si se esta ejecutando el metodo grabarFicheroTexto() entonces el objeto quedara bloqueado para que no se pueda acceder a el dentro del bloque `synchronized` desde otro hilo hasta que termine lo que mantendra la ejecución sincronizada.

Para lograr esto crea una variable statica que sera el semafaro entre el acceso a un metodo o otro y la utilizas dentro del bloque `synchronized(lock){ ... }`:

```
public class Ejercicio7 extends Thread
{       

   public static readonly Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread hilo1 = new Ejercicio7(); hilo1.setName("hilo1");
        Thread hilo2 = new Ejercicio7(); hilo2.setName("hilo2");

        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("hilo1"))
        {
            grabarFicheroTexto();
        }
        else
        {           
            try {
                leerFicheroTexto();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}          
        }
    }

    public static void grabarFicheroTexto()
    {

        synchronized(lock)
        {
            char c;
            try{
                System.out.println("Vas a escribir en un fichero de texto en Java\n");
                System.out.print("Escribe aqui: ");
                FileWriter fichero=new FileWriter("..\\Threads\\src\\ejercicio7\\Archivo.txt");
                StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
                while ((c=(char)System.in.read())!='\n')
                    str.append(c);
                String cadena=new String(str);  
                fichero.write(cadena);          

                if (fichero!=null)
                    fichero.close();
            }catch(IOException ex){}
            System.out.println("FICHERO ESCRITO CORRECTAMENTE");

        }
    }
    public static void leerFicheroTexto()throws IOException
    {
        synchronized(lock){

            System.out.println("Estas leyendo un fichero de texto en Java\n");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("..\\Threads\\src\\ejercicio7\\Archivo.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s;

            while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(s);
            }
            fr.close();
        }
    }
}
```